# Script fails when using a variable for paths

Tags: unix

The following script fails. If I run it manually by giving absolute paths instead of a DIR it works.

```
#!/bin/ksh
export DIR="/clocal/www/logs/CA"
find  $DIR -name "*gz" -mtime +2 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
#Working line : find . -name "*gz" -mtime +2 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
```

The operating system this is being run under is AIX.

Comment: Operating System is AIX

Comment: your code works fine under Solaris. 
Have you tried to debug it? e.g. to echo "$DIR" after assignment, change var name (maybe $DIR is some kind of system var, like $PWD, in AIX)?

Comment: This may not help this work, but `DIR` doesn't need to be exported.  Consider just using `DIR=/whatever/it/was`.  Also, to guard against someone accidentally throwing a space in the value of `DIR`, you may want to double quote the argument to `find`.  Also, consider tacking `-x` to your shebang line to see what the shell is running.  This may reveal some details.

Comment: $ uname -a
AIX

$ DIR="/clocal/www/logs/CA"

$ echo $DIR
/clocal/www/logs/CA

$ find  $DIR -name "*gz" -mtime +2 -exec ls -lrt {} \;

Comment: It didn't work either.

Comment: even this command is not working.                                                          find /clocal/www/logs/CA -name "*gz" -mtime +2 -exec ls -lrt {} \;

Comment: following command is working.                                                                          find . -name "*gz" -mtime +2 -exec ls -lrt {} \;

Comment: I found the issue. /clocal/www/logs/CA is soft link to CA -> /clocal/www/logs/Netegrity. I have used -L option. It is working fine

Comment: Solution :                                                                                                  find  -L $DIR -name "*gz" -mtime +2 -exec ls -lrt {} \;